# How do I copy a docker image to a remote machine?

Tags: docker

I have a Docker image that I've built:

```
» docker images --no-trunc | grep discoball/nginx
discoball/nginx                 latest              623444f1777c        21 hours ago        126 MB
```

I'd like to move this to a remote server; `docker save` and `docker load` appear to be commands capable of serializing and de-serializing an image to/from a file, which should be exactly what I need. However, I'm not able to actually get these to work.

I save the image:

```
» docker save discoball/nginx > nginx-latest.tar.gz
```

Then attempt to restore it on the remote:

```
» cat nginx-latest.tar.gz | ssh "$IP" docker load
```

That command executes successfully. However, `docker images` on the remote indicates that the image didn't make it; rather, what appears to be an old version is still present:

```
» ssh "$IP" docker images --no-trunc | grep discoball/nginx
discoball/nginx        latest              2678dc27dd46        21 hours ago        126 MB
```

Note that the Image ID is different; I'm guessing that this is an old version of my image. Searching for the image ID itself also yields no results on the server:

```
» ssh "$IP" docker images --all | grep 623444
(last command returned 1.)
»
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

So now I'm digging around in the generated `.tar.gz` file; the `repositories` file in it seems to indicate that the remote machine has it right:

```
» tar -xf nginx-latest.tar.gz -O repositories
{"discoball/nginx":{"latest":"2678dc27dd46469bc8692c2e5ad71b57ae573b1444531fcd1f76798638f84f5c"}}
```

That's the number I see on the remote. But why the heck did `docker save` write that out, and not `623444f1777c`? (Are docker image IDs not just cryptographic hashes of the image and/or layer?) If the remote *does* have the same image, why does it have a different image ID? (I don't know how to verify that at the moment, because up until this moment, I would have said that "same image" was "same image ID"…)

Answer (score 0):

On your local machine

```
docker save MYIMAGE:TAG -o myimage.tgz
```

Copy `myimage.tgz` to the remote machine and, there, you can

```
docker load -i myimage.tgz
```

If anything, it might be easier to transfer the `Dockerfile` and its artifacts and just build a new image in the remote server directly. Whatever works better for you.